# Does there exist a program that can show me the differences between two executables?

Tags: binary, patch, disassembly, ida

Does there exist a program that can show me the differences between two executables?

I need a program that takes two executables as input and can generate a diff file with all the differences.

Comment: Could you provide more information as to why you need to compare these two executable.

Comment: Various binary diff tools float around the internet, including [this one](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/).

Comment: To see the differences. For example I need to see which are the patch that some others make to a binary file. I need to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is BinDiff: http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html
Take a look at the screenshots to see how it works, and what are its outputs. It's not free, but the price is quite reasonable ($200) for what it offers.